# Cards and columns?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I have a deck of cards which I arrange in 4 rows (13 columns). If I pick one card from each column, how do I show that it's possible to get one card from each rank? I know that I have to use the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: Oops, I mean each rank.. Let me change that.

Comment: You aren't guaranteed that.  You could, for example,  get $2\clubsuit$ from the first column and $2\diamondsuit$ from the second.

Comment: Are you perhaps saying that there is **some** way to pick one card from each column so that you get every rank?

Comment: Again, I worded the question wrong. Let's say it's because of loss of sleep and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, If you just flatten out a shuffled deck in $4$ rows and pick $1$ card from each column, then this is equivalent to picking $13$ random cards from a deck.

I'm not sure why you accepted this answer when [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews) provided a short explanation involving the pigeon principle you asked about: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1685770

Comment: Where'd you get the $n-1$ from? I get where the $+1$ comes from, but $n-1$?

Comment: Can I use the regular $floor(n/m)$ pigeonhole principle with 52 pigeons and 13 holes? Is that valid logic?

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helps.

Comment: I don't think this argument works. What are the "holes"? How does this argument ensure that you can pick a card from each column to get one card of each rank?

Answer (score 3):

You probably need pigeonhole along with the [Hall's marriage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).

Using Hall's theorem, you need to show that any $n$ columns has at least $n$ different ranks. Since $n$ columns contain $4n$ cards, and there are only four cards of each rank, there cannot be fewer than $n$ different ranks in the set. (That is the application of the pigeonhole principle.)

Comment: Hall's Marriage Theorem is how David Leep and I handled this exact question at the beginning of our paper, Marriage, magic, and solitaire, Amer. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) 419-429.